# How to find the next Anchor tag from previous in htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

```
<html>
<a href="#id_1">Some Text</a>

<div>
Some Text.
</div>

<div>
Some Text
</div>

<a href="#id_2">Some Text</a>

</html>
```

I Want to find anchor tag id_2 based on the first one i.e id_1 without using foreach loop on html Page.
I have tried the following code :

```
   HtmlNode dtElement= doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href = '#id_1' ]");

   private static HtmlNode GetNextDDSibling(HtmlNode dtElement)
    {
        var currentNode = dtElement;

        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;

         if (currentNode.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && currentNode.Name == "a")
                return currentNode;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a `foreach` loop when you would use a `while` loop? Using a `foreach` loop could very well be _the_ way to go.

Comment: Jeff, i have used while loop to find next anchor tag from previous, not to find all anchor tags.Actually i want to find id_1 and id_2 with Id_1 inner text that's why. Any Suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing you could do here is use a particular xpath query to select the next sibling anchor.

```
private static HtmlNode GetNextDDSibling(HtmlNode element)
{
    return element.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::a");
}
```

Comment: But its not working if first anchor tab is inside a table or div?

Comment: Well this query will only select the next _sibling_ anchor, not a descendant, ancestor or other. If you wanted those, that's where the `foreach` loops would come into play.